# how to inherit C++ classes generated by protobuf

Tags: c++, protobuf-c, protocol-buffers

I have created one message

mesage 1
{
member1,
}

after compilation it generates c++ code,

How can we inherit generated classes.

after inheriting, getting below error

cannot derive from ‘final’ base

Comment: They're final, because they won't serialise correctly if you inherit .... are you sure you don't mean to use composition rather than inheritance?

Answer (score 2):

> How can we inherit generated classes.

You **can't**. That is **by design**.